# i have Two array i want that unique value of array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let array1 = ["apple", "banana", "mango"];
let array2 = ["apple", "banana", "mango", "red", "green"];

I want output is = array3 = [ "red", "green"];
```

I want to concat array1 and array2 and remove the duplicate code and output is array3.

> There are two common ways (in ES5 and ES6, respectively) of getting unique values in JavaScript arrays of primitive values. Basically, in ES5, you first define a distinct callback to check if a value first occurs in the original array, then filter the original array so that only first-occurred elements are kept.

Comment: Why did you quote a paragraph from other source?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter out the common elements using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as:

```js
let array1 = ["apple", "banana", "mango"];
let array2 = ["apple", "banana", "mango", "red", "green"];

const map = [...array1, ...array2].reduce(
  (map, curr) => map.set(curr, (map.get(curr) ?? 0) + 1),
  new Map()
);

const result = [];
for (let [k, v] of map) {
  if (v === 1) result.push(k);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `I want to concat array1 and array2 and remove the duplicate code and output is array3.` Will this capture unique items in array1?

Comment: No It won't capture, because unique values are stored in `Set` not in `array1` or `array2`

Comment: What I mean is what if array1 is `["apple", "banana", "mango", "orange"]` and array2 is the same. What is the expected result?

Comment: @Mark Answer edited...